# Codility code causes segmentation fault

Tags: c++, primes

Here's my solution for Count Semiprimes codility problem, which is correct for small and medium inputs but results in segmentation fault for large test cases.

https://codility.com/demo/results/demo8JU794-FC7/

This normally happens with invalid pointers etc. however I can't see anything here which could cause such behaviour.

Are you able to spot anything wrong with the code?

```
vector<int> solution(int N, vector<int> &P, vector<int> &Q) {

    int M = P.size();

    // Use sieve of eratosthenes to find prime numbers within range 0 to N
    vector<int> sieve(N+1);
    sieve[0] = sieve[1] = 0;

    for (int i = 2; i <= N; ++i)
    {
        if (sieve[i] == 0)
        {
            int k = i * i;
            while(k <= N)
            {
                // For each non prime store its lowest prime divisor.
                sieve[k] = i;
                k += i;
            }
        }
    }

    vector<int> answer(M);

    for (int i = 0; i < M; ++i)
    {
        // Count semiprimes for each range (P[i], Q[i])
        int count = 0;

        for(int j = P[i]; j <= Q[i]; ++j)
        {
            // If a number is divisible by prime and the result of this division is also a prime
            // Then it's a semiprime.
            if (sieve[j] != 0 && sieve[j / sieve[j]] == 0)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        answer[i] = count;
    }

    return answer;
}
```

Comment: You will actually wind up storing its *highest* prime divisor, not its lowest, in `sieve`.

Comment: How come? `i` is not changed inside the while loop, only `k`. `i` is the lowest prime divisor which multiples `k` are then set as non primes.

Comment: Consider 21. When processing 3, you will set sieve[21] to 3. But then when processing 7, you will set sieve[21] to 7.

Comment: Ah damn, you're right. I need another if statement there to check whether the divisor has already been set. Let's see if that changes anything though.

Comment: Nope, still getting a segfault: https://codility.com/demo/results/demo8VXUGQ-9QU/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this part, for N = 50000  the result of `k = i * i` overflows an int which is the reason for the segfault.

```
    if (sieve[i] == 0)
    {
        int k = i * i;
        while(k <= N)
        {
            // For each non prime store its lowest prime divisor.
            sieve[k] = i;
            k += i;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you post where the seg fault is at?

Just from the looks, `sieve[0] = sieve[1] = 0;` will exhibit undefined behavior when N is 0.

Comment: From the problem description: `N is an integer within the range [1..50,000];`. I have no idea where the segfault happens. You can see compilation output at: https://codility.com/demo/results/demo8JU794-FC7/

Comment: Then start learning using debugging tools. You can't program anything without them!